# Spring Boot Kafka listener is inconsistent

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, apache-kafka, spring-cloud

I am trying to have several different Spring Cloud Microservices all connect to a Kafka/Zookeeper Cluster, all within Kubernetes. The Microservices are using `org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka` - as both consumers and producers of events.

All of the services connect to kafka okay - and topics are created; however the consumers of each service are very inconsistent.

For example, when the services start one time, all of the consumers will listen for the message and the function is invoked. But then, when I restart everything (kafka and zookeeper included), it will either just not work, or some of the consumers in different services will work etc...

Here is some of my config - I don't have any Java-based config - just in my application.yml as follows:

```
spring:

  ....

  kafka:
    consumer:
      bootstrap-servers: api-kafka.default.svc.cluster.local:9092
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      group-id: api-event
      enable-auto-commit: false

    producer:
      bootstrap-servers: api-kafka.default.svc.cluster.local:9092
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      value-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      ack-mode: manual

...
```

And my main class:

```
@EnableCaching
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableKafka /* <<<<<<<------------- ENABLED HERE */
public class ExampleServiceApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ExampleServiceApplication.class, args);
  }

  .....
}
```

And finally, my consumer:

```
@Component
public class MessageListener {

  @KafkaListener(
      topics = "myTopic")
  public void eventListener(String serializedMessage) {
    try {
....
```

The messages are getting sent to the broker fine, but just aren't consumed by the other services.

I realize that there is no mapping to the topics on each of the service properties, how do I do this via application.yml?

I bet I'm making a really nooby mistake but yeah! I'd really appreciate any comments or help

Comment: how many partitions your kafka topic has? If you have one partition then it is normal that only one service to consume the messages. If you want more services to consume the topic messages in parallel, then you need to increase the number of partitions.

Comment: @OctavianR. Oh okay - interesting - didn't know that! As far as I know, I only have single partition for all of the services so that could be it... I guess I'd need to define Java beans which have the NewTopic Type and build the topics with the right number of partitions. Thanks for the comment - I'll try now

Comment: But there are different topics for each entity with EventTypes as fields etc...- But that shouldn't affect it much

Comment: No, should not matter at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Btw, you can read here more about the relation between the number of partitions and the number of parallel consumers (consumers with the same group id).

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/architecture.html

> Slightly simplified, the maximum parallelism at which your application may run is bounded by the maximum number of stream tasks, which itself is determined by maximum number of partitions of the input topic(s) the application is reading from. For example, if your input topic has 5 partitions, then you can run up to 5 applications instances. These instances will collaboratively process the topic’s data. If you run a larger number of app instances than partitions of the input topic, the “excess” app instances will launch but remain idle; however, if one of the busy instances goes down, one of the idle instances will resume the former’s work. We provide a more detailed explanation and example in the FAQ.

Comment: I'm reading the confluent docs atm while running my services in minikube locally. I currently have 1 replica of each service, but let's say I had 2 for each service - is this article saying I can or it can't - or does it just go idle until needed?

Comment: You can have it, but the consumers who exceeds the number of partitions will stay idle,

Comment: Nice thanks for your help - just doing a few more tests and I'll mark your answer right!